# ANTLR4 Grammar Performance Very Poor

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Given the grammar below, I'm seeing very poor performance when parsing longer strings, on the order of seconds. (this on both Python and Go implementations) Is there something in this grammar that is causing that?

Example output:

```
0.000061s LEXING "hello world"
0.014349s PARSING "hello world"
0.000052s LEXING 5 + 10
0.015384s PARSING 5 + 10
0.000061s LEXING FIRST_WORD(WORD_SLICE(contact.blerg, 2, 4))
0.634113s PARSING FIRST_WORD(WORD_SLICE(contact.blerg, 2, 4))
0.000095s LEXING (DATEDIF(DATEVALUE("01-01-1970"), date.now, "D") * 24 * 60 * 60) + ((((HOUR(date.now)+7) * 60) + MINUTE(date.now)) * 60))
1.552758s PARSING (DATEDIF(DATEVALUE("01-01-1970"), date.now, "D") * 24 * 60 * 60) + ((((HOUR(date.now)+7) * 60) + MINUTE(date.now)) * 60))
```

This is on Python.. though I don't expect blazing performance I would expect sub-second for any input. What am I doing wrong?

```
grammar Excellent;

parse
  : expr EOF
  ;

expr
  :  atom                                                    # expAtom
  |  concatenationExpr                                       # expConcatenation
  |  equalityExpr                                            # expEquality
  |  comparisonExpr                                          # expComparison
  |  additionExpr                                            # expAddition
  |  multiplicationExpr                                      # expMultiplication
  |  exponentExpr                                            # expExponent
  |  unaryExpr                                               # expUnary
  ;

path
  :  NAME (step)*
  ;

step
  : LBRAC expr RBRAC
  | PATHSEP NAME
  | PATHSEP NUMBER
  ;

parameters
  : expr (COMMA expr)*                                       # functionParameters
  ;

concatenationExpr
  : atom (AMP concatenationExpr)?                            # concatenation
  ;

equalityExpr
  :  comparisonExpr op=(EQ|NE) comparisonExpr                # equality
  ;

comparisonExpr
  :  additionExpr (op=(LT|GT|LTE|GTE) additionExpr)?         # comparison
  ;

additionExpr
  :  multiplicationExpr (op=(ADD|SUB) multiplicationExpr)*   # addition
  ;

multiplicationExpr
  :  exponentExpr (op=(MUL|DIV) exponentExpr)*               # multiplication
  ;

exponentExpr
  :  unaryExpr (EXP exponentExpr)?                           # exponent
  ;

unaryExpr
  : SUB? atom                                                # negation
  ;

funcCall
  : function=NAME LPAR parameters? RPAR                      # functionCall
  ;

funcPath
  : function=funcCall (step)*                                # functionPath
  ;

atom
  :  path                                                    # contextReference
  |  funcCall                                                # atomFuncCall
  |  funcPath                                                # atomFuncPath
  |  LITERAL                                                 # stringLiteral
  |  NUMBER                                                  # decimalLiteral
  |  LPAR expr RPAR                                          # parentheses
  |  TRUE                                                    # true
  |  FALSE                                                   # false
  ;

NUMBER
  :  DIGITS ('.' DIGITS?)?
  ;

fragment
DIGITS
  :  ('0'..'9')+
  ;

TRUE
  : [Tt][Rr][Uu][Ee]
  ;

FALSE
  : [Ff][Aa][Ll][Ss][Ee]
  ;

PATHSEP
       :'.';
LPAR
       :'(';
RPAR
       :')';
LBRAC
       :'[';
RBRAC
       :']';
SUB
       :'-';
ADD
       :'+';
MUL
       :'*';
DIV
       :'/';
COMMA
       :',';
LT
       :'<';
GT
       :'>';
EQ
       :'=';
NE
       :'!=';
LTE
       :'<=';
GTE
       :'>=';
QUOT
       :'"';
EXP
       : '^';
AMP
       : '&';

LITERAL
  :  '"' ~'"'* '"'
  ;

Whitespace
  :  (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r')+ ->skip
  ;

NAME
  :  NAME_START_CHARS NAME_CHARS*
  ;

fragment
NAME_START_CHARS
  :  'A'..'Z'
  |   '_'
  |  'a'..'z'
  |  '\u00C0'..'\u00D6'
  |  '\u00D8'..'\u00F6'
  |  '\u00F8'..'\u02FF'
  |  '\u0370'..'\u037D'
  |  '\u037F'..'\u1FFF'
  |  '\u200C'..'\u200D'
  |  '\u2070'..'\u218F'
  |  '\u2C00'..'\u2FEF'
  |  '\u3001'..'\uD7FF'
  |  '\uF900'..'\uFDCF'
  |  '\uFDF0'..'\uFFFD'
  ;

fragment
NAME_CHARS
  :  NAME_START_CHARS
  | '0'..'9'
  |  '\u00B7' | '\u0300'..'\u036F'
  |  '\u203F'..'\u2040'
  ;

ERRROR_CHAR
  : .
  ;
```

Comment: What is your `contact.blerg`?

Comment: Which version of ANTLR4 are you using?

Comment: I'm using Antlr 4.7

Answer (score 3):

You can always try to parse with `SLL(*)` first and only if that fails you need to parse it with `LL(*)` (which is the default).

See [this](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/192) ticket on ANTLR's GitHub for further explaination and [here](https://github.com/Krzmbrzl/SQDev/blob/f6281391bf9598021fc96761611bc0e9f065d74b/plugin/Raven.SQDev.SQFEditor/src/raven/sqdev/editors/sqfeditor/SQF_Editor.java#L295) is an implementation that uses this strategy.

This method will save you (a lot of) time when parsing syntactically correct input.

Comment: Is there a significant performance difference between `SLL(*)` and `LL(*)` in practical case? LL(*) might have more ambiguity when doing top-down parsing, how will this ambiguity influence the performance?

Comment: Yes there is... I had files that took ~20 seconds to parse with `LL(*)` and ~600ms with `SLL(*)`. And I have never experienced a case where `SLL(*)` failed for syntactically correct input. If it does the parser will switch back `LL(*)` so the time used for the `SLL(*)` parsing done before will be "wasted" in that case. But as I said I have never experienced that for valid input

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this performance is due to the left recursion used in the addition / multiplication etc, operators. Rewriting these to be binary rules instead yields performance that is instant. (see below)

```
grammar Excellent;

COMMA      : ',';
LPAREN     : '(';
RPAREN     : ')';
LBRACK     : '[';
RBRACK     : ']';

DOT        : '.';

PLUS       : '+';
MINUS      : '-';
TIMES      : '*';
DIVIDE     : '/';
EXPONENT   : '^';

EQ         : '=';
NEQ        : '!=';

LTE        : '<=';
LT         : '<';
GTE        : '>=';
GT         : '>';

AMPERSAND  : '&';

DECIMAL    : [0-9]+('.'[0-9]+)?;
STRING     : '"' (~["] | '""')* '"';

TRUE       : [Tt][Rr][Uu][Ee];
FALSE      : [Ff][Aa][Ll][Ss][Ee];

NAME       : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.]*;    // variable names, e.g. contact.name or function names, e.g. SUM

WS         : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;        // ignore whitespace

ERROR      : . ;

parse      : expression EOF;

atom       : fnname LPAREN parameters? RPAREN             # functionCall
           | atom DOT atom                                # dotLookup
           | atom LBRACK expression RBRACK                # arrayLookup
           | NAME                                         # contextReference
           | STRING                                       # stringLiteral
           | DECIMAL                                      # decimalLiteral
           | TRUE                                         # true
           | FALSE                                        # false
           ;

expression : atom                                         # atomReference
           | MINUS expression                             # negation
           | expression EXPONENT expression               # exponentExpression
           | expression (TIMES | DIVIDE) expression       # multiplicationOrDivisionExpression
           | expression (PLUS | MINUS) expression         # additionOrSubtractionExpression
           | expression (LTE | LT | GTE | GT) expression  # comparisonExpression
           | expression (EQ | NEQ) expression             # equalityExpression
           | expression AMPERSAND expression              # concatenation
           | LPAREN expression RPAREN                     # parentheses
           ;

fnname     : NAME
           | TRUE
           | FALSE
           ;

parameters : expression (COMMA expression)*               # functionParameters
           ;
```

Comment: Can it be that you confused your grammars here? The grammar in this answer uses left recursions, while the one in your question does not. This contradicts your answer text where you say that left recursion removal lead to better performance.

Comment: Entirely possible I have my nomenclature incorrect, will leave the examples and grammars as examples so others can figure it out though.